# Installation failed after switch from release mode to debug mode android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have built an app for my client and I have put that apk on playstore. now my clients want to some additional changes to that app. I have changed my build variants from release mode to debug mode.And I try to install the app but android studio throws an error during installation.

[image: This is the error I am getting]

I have uninstalled the app manually from my phone but I don't how this is an error is occurring and how I can able to install the app on the device.

Comment: read the error and click OK.

Comment: This popup shows if the app is installed but signed with a different cert.

Comment: I have done brother but still same issue ....@VivekMishra please remove downvote cause I have already that thing.

Comment: check certificate , by default apk will be signed by debug certificate.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try disabling instant run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already installed apk from Playstore and without uninstalling this,you are trying to run your application in debug mode.It is not possible.so first of all you should uninstall your apk in phone which you downloaded earlier from play store.After that you can run your application from Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using The Redmi/ mi devices please turn off the MIUI Optimizations. In My case, the same thing has happened. 
To turn off the MIUI Optimization goto Settings->additional Settings -> developer Option

find MIUI Optimization turn it to off and reboot your device.